# Is it ok to harmonize a descending soprano with V for ^7?

Tags: voice-leading

[image]

I am trying to compose some music and practice my 4 part harmony skills. I have been taught that a leading tone as shown here in my soprano should ascend or be harmonized with a iii if descending but I cant understand why I cant use a dominant chord here. Perhaps this is something that is just a rule in the early stages and as I carry on learning it will become clear when the leading tone should ascend and when not? In this context I really cant see how it sounds odd.

Comment: Your chord symbols at the end are inconsistent, with both F/A and Dm being labelled as i chords with no key change indication in between.

Comment: Sorry,I wasnt finished...  can you just not look at that now? It is not relevant to the post anyway

Comment: That's probably why @Dekkadeci posted it as a comment rather than as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Without wanting to get into a discussion about whether it's acceptable, or, more precisely, under which conditions it might be acceptable, I will offer the example of Bach's setting of *Ach Herr, laß dein lieb Engelein* from the St. John Passion:

The melody, in movable *do*, begins *do-ti-la-sol,* and the corresponding chords are `I-V-vi-iii`.

Comment: YouTube's thumbnail image is _not_ the beginning of the music where the melody descendings `8 7 6 5`, be sure to start the video to see the example passage.

Comment: This harmonization of ^8 ^7 ^6 ^5 is beautiful. Why on earth does my harmony book say that the sopranos leading tone needs to resolve? These seem like silly rules to me now.

Comment: @armani there may be some context in which that rule does apply, and this context may be different for some reason.  Or maybe it's just a poorly formulated rule.

Comment: phoog, that is why I created the post to try see if anyone could maybe show an example where you really do want to resolve the LT.. maybe at a cadence it is necessary and at other times should be discarded. This is how I am making sense of it.

Comment: @armani if it's a cadence then the following note wouldn't be ^6.  In a chorale harmonization, the melody is given.  If all instances of ^7 in a melody had to resolve upward, there'd be no such thing as a descending major scale.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is about harmonizing the scale descent `^8 ^7 ^6 ^5`.

I had a question about the same in [How to complete a scale harmonization using Quantz' Versuch](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/99731) and @Athanasius gave a nice detailed answer to my question which I think will be helpful to you too.

The special treatment of the descending melodic line `^8 ^7 ^6 ^5` is when all of the tones are true harmonic tones.

In your specific example I would point out that your line involves *passing motion* and is essentially a decoration and voicing change of the tonic chord.

The reduction would be this...

[image]

Then some possibilities to fill that in rhythmically...

[image]

In the second option, the change of `G4` to `F4` in the tenor essentially makes the soprano `E5 D5` all passing motion between `F5` and `C5`.

The third option uses your original tenor, but then has the soprano move back up to `F5` which makes `E5` a chord tone and the `D5` a kind of escape tone. Obviously that changes the top line, but it still treats the larger harmonic structure as a revoicing of the tonic chord.

Given the fact that you can find parallel and direct perfect fifths and octaves occasionally in the works of the great masters, I think it's safe to say that all three of those examples above are OK, and more or less the same thing.

Comment: Nice! ok so the fact that there is a passing motion I suppose the leading tone is kind of hidden away between the other notes which is why I wasnt getting a need to resolve it. Well my textbook annoyingly says that a leading tone in the soprano must resolve. It does not give exceptions yet. Perhaps this is still coming in a later chapter (im only half way)